# Printf additional newline with inserting a string value in printf

Tags: c, printf

```
printf("It is currently %s's turn.\n", current->name);
```

I'm wondering why this is printing out additional newline after the %s. I am aware that strings in C always ends with \0. How do I print it without it?

Comment: `current->name` has a new-line at the end of it.

Comment: And strings always end with `\0`, `\n` is just a new-line character.

Comment: Yeah but how to do remove the newline for printing? Because current-> is from a user input

Comment: It would be worth your time to investigate why `current->name` is suffixed with a `\n` in the first place. My two cents, it's bad practice to mix in formatting characters directly with your data.

Comment: The string was probably read in from the user initially using `fgets`, which retains the newline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable `current->name` has a newline in it, so you need to get rid of that newline.

```
current->name[strcspn(current->name, "\n")] = '\0';
```

This piece of code will help you get rid of the unwanted newline. Put it before `printf`.

Comment: @LimEweWin Typical cryptic C function ;) It's explained [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strcspn.php)

Comment: You can read it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcspn.htm). It's a good function.

Comment: Reputation in the bank